# Handling worksheet_change event before dependent formulas are calculated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a use case where there's a cell for user input, and a bunch of other cells with formulas dependent on this cell. My intention is to sanitize the data before the formulas are calculated. These formulas can be quite expensive, so I'd like to prevent having them calculated on garbage data if possible. So I wanted to have some vba code check the input and clean it up before the formula calculation is fired. I set up a Worksheet_Change event to handle the user input, however, unfortunately, it would seem that dependent cells are calculated even before Worksheet_Change() is entered. Anyway I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

First, switch off auto-calculate by choosing `Manual` from the `Calculation Options` on the `Formulas` menu.

Then add this line at the end of your cleaning-up code, to cause the workbook to calculate:

```
Application.Calculate
```

This will update all those formulas with the new cleaned value, before Excel does the calculation (since auto-calc is switched off).

If you are worried about the user switching auto-calc back on, hence slowing down the calculations, you could add this further line to switch it off again as soon as possible:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Note: maybe this is anti-social because I think the auto-calc option in Excel is instance-wide, so would affect the users' other spreadsheets. You could perhaps get round this with some code in the `Workbook_Open` event, to remember the state of the `Application.Calculation` property, then switch it off (as above), and then some code in the `Workbook_Close` event to restore it again. It may be advisable for the users to make sure they use your workbook alone in an Excel instance, to be sure of no inconvenience to them!

**Edit**: just on the last note, better to use `Workbook_Activate` and `Workbook_Deactivate` instead of `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_Close`.

With that, here is the code, to go into your `ThisWorkbook` object.

```
Public previousCalculationState As XlCalculation


Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    previousCalculationState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.Calculation = previousCalculationState
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print "before clean: G6 = " & Range("G6").Value ' this shows that G6 has the old value, before calc

    ' your cleaning code to go here, which can use Sh and Target to find out which cell changed

    Application.Calculate
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Debug.Print "after clean: G6 = " & Range("G6").Value ' this shows that G6 has the new value, after calc
    Debug.Print

End Sub
```

This code includes some `Debug.Print`s, which assume you have a formula in cell G6 on each sheet, and which prove that your cleaning code is happening before the formulas are calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this won't work for me because I need the Calculation to be interactive. Now I could turn off calculation if I could put the code somewhere when the user input cell is changed but that brings us back to the same question: where do I put that code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. With my suggestion your calculation will still be interactive - it will happen automatically whenever something is changed. It will happen after your cleaning code. Isn't that what you wanted? Have you tried it?

Comment: Well, I can't just turn Calculation to Manual because then the rest of the spreadsheet won't work.

Comment: It will because of your `Application.Calculate` line. Which will happen after every change. Because it is in the worksheet change event.

Comment: I do not follow. The spreadsheet itself has other formulas that need to work regardless of whether the input cell changes or not.

Comment: Excel's worksheet change event fires when _any_ cell changes. Not just your input cell. So the other formulas will still work, in the sense that any time the user makes a change, all the formulas will be updated. This is all auto calculate does. On a change, it recalculates. With my solution, you are just telling it to do the calc after your cleaning code, wherease with auto calc, it happens before it gets to your cleaning code. Apart from that difference, my solution is the same as Excel's normal auto calc behaviour.

Comment: So, set Calculation to manual on Open, in change event, if it's the input cell, clean up, end if. Call .Calculate regardless of which cell changed. Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: Yes. However, I since had a better idea than using the open / close events - and instead to use the activate / deactivate events instead, to switch off autocalc. Let me add this to my answer ...